# Error message when running custom .bst file in bibtex

Tags: bibtex, custom-bib

I have created a custom `.bst` file with the makebst program. Whenever I run BibTeX on it I first get the following error:

```
z is an unknown function --- line 169 of file eup.bst
```

Then for all entries in the bib file i get (where Aldrich1995 is the first example):

```
"Aldrich JH" is a string literal, not a function, for entry Aldrich1995
while executing --- line 1431 of file eup.bst
You cant pop an empty literal stack for Aldrich1995
```

I am a beginner with `.bst` files so I have no idea what is going on here.

P.S: a link to the file:
http://www.easy-share.com/1916347685/eup.bst

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) It's not necessary to sign your questions (as there is already a box with your username below it) or to begin them with a greeting.

Comment: Did you just use makebst, or did you also customise anything afterwards? Can you post your `.bst` file somewhere we can see?

Answer (score 3):

The string `z` is used in the `.bst` file but not declared. Change the line

```
STRINGS { s t}
```

to

```
STRINGS { s t z }
```

and the problem should go away. (If there are further errors, please construct a minimal LaTeX + BibTeX example, as I have done in my answer to [Hyphenating a number in the BibTeX pages field](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21773/hyphenating-a-number-in-the-bibtex-pages-field).)