# page numbers in bibliography file

Tags: bibliographies, ieeetran

I'm using

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}    
\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{IEEEabrv,bibliography}
\end{document}
```

One reference in my biliography.bib file I have:

```
pages = {IV-921-IV-924}
```

I want the first and the last hyphen to be the size of a hyphen but the middle one to be longer. But, the editor formats them all as long hyphens(en-dash). It does not differentiate between the middle hyphen which should be formatted as en-dash and others (which are part of page numbers) as hyphens.
How to correct?

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21773/hyphenating-a-number-in-the-bibtex-pages-field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
pages           = {IV\-921-IV\-924}
```

or

```
pages           = {IV{\-}921-IV{\-}924}
```

Comment: This way I get a very long middle hyphen and two long hyphens. Rather, I want the two exterior hyphens to be short (like the normal hyphens).

Comment: Normal in the middle and shorter in the "extremes"?

Comment: Longer in the middle and normal in the "extremes". The problem is the editor translates the hyphen in biblio 'pages ={1-2}' to a long hyphen.

Comment: @Elnaz I edited my answer, now with small hyphens. Try it!